# Tabs in the actionbar with mvvmcross

Tags: mvvmcross

Using mvvmcross it's posible to put tabs in the action bar as the Android documentation suggest?, I've seen the Fragment sample and notice that the tabs are inside a TabHost, the same approach would be perfect but using the action bar instead.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great example how to do it from cheesbaron:
http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/07/fragments-and-viewpager-with-mvx.html

Comment: Sorry for not answering sonner... I´ll test the example and let you know... Thanks