# Swipe tab fragment with mvvmcross

Tags: mvvmcross

I want to use swipe to switch tab in the Fragments tutorial. I cannot find an example of this. Is this part of mvvmcross?

Answer (score 0):

I've find this for you : [Tabs in the actionbar with mvvmcross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271805/tabs-in-the-actionbar-with-mvvmcross)

Try searching for "mvvmcross tab fragment" on here and hopefully you will find quite a few helpful questions https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmvvmcross%5D+tab+fragment